# User idle time being reset to 0 after 30 secs on Linux

Tags: linux, x11, gnome, screensaver, idle-timer

I am trying to detect time since last user input using the X11 Screen Saver extension client library. I make periodic calls to `XScreenSaverQueryInfo` to get the idle time. The problem I am facing is that after every 20-30 seconds the idle time, as reported by this call, resets to 0. This happens even though there has been no actual user input in that time. I am totally puzzled by this. The only lead I have is that the problem disappears if I uninstall `gnome-screensaver`. My question is, does the `gnome-screensaver` simulate user inputs for some reason? I know it sounds unlikely, and if it does, it will most definitely be a bug with `gnome-screensaver`, but I cannot think of anything else right now. Does anyone know where I can find more information on how `gnome-screensaver` works and how it influences the `XScreenSaverQueryInfo` call without actually having to go through the code. I have gone through the info at `gnome-screensaver` [home](http://live.gnome.org/GnomeScreensaver) but could not find anything relevant to my issue.

**Update**: I got the following output from dbus-monitor. How do I interpret this:

```
method call sender=:1.97538 -> dest=org.gnome.ScreenSaver serial=3 path=/org/gnome/ScreenSaver; interface=org.gnome.ScreenSaver; member=SimulateUserActivity
```

I think some process is asking gnome-screensaver to SimulateUserActivity. Or, is gnome-screensaver sending a SimulateUserActivity signal to dbus? If it is the first, how can I find out which process is asking gnome-screensaver to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have the dbus sender (as shown on dbus-monitor there) you can do:

```
dbus-send --print-reply --dest=org.freedesktop.DBus /org/freedesktop/DBus org.freedesktop.DBus.GetConnectionUnixProcessID string:':1.97538'
```

plugging in the actual sender. That gives you the pid that's sending the message.

Then say the pid is 2144, you'd do:

```
cat /proc/2144/cmdline
```

as one way to see what the program is.

Comment: I did that. It says: 

    Error org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NameHasNoOwner: Could not get PID of name ':1.ddddd': no such name

Here, 1.ddddd is the actual sender.

Comment: that points to something connecting, sending the SimulateUserActivity, then disconnecting before you can investigate. Maybe the gnome-screensaver-command --poke mentioned above. The suggestion to replace gnome-screensaver-command with a shell script is an interesting one.

Answer (score 3):

A program (video players does this while playing video) might be sending a `gnome-screensaver-command --poke` command which will send a `SimulateUserActivity` event to reset the idle time which will prevent screensaver becoming active.

Comment: I do not have any foreground processes running. Is there any way I can query which application might be doing that?

Comment: You can overwrite gnome-screen-command program with a shell script which will print out who is calling it. Of course someone might just be using the DBus interface instead.

Comment: I have updated my question to include output from dbus-monitor. Any idea what it means?

Comment: Yes some program is poking screensaver to inhibit it from starting. Just like I guessed.