# How can I check a user's idle time in Linux?

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, cloud, digital-ocean, screensaver

I have a cluster of virtual machines on cloud (Digital Oceans), and I want to find a way to turn them off if they are idle for at least 1 hour.

I imagine it is similar to how a screensaver decides to kick in after an appointed duration of idle, or how some cloud services like Snowflake or Databricks can turn off resources if they are not used for a duration.

I have checked the `w` command and do not find any info that can tell me idle time, although that command's output has an idle column.

If you know how a screensaver kicks in, or how cloud services turn off resources, please share. Much appreciated.

=== UPDATE ===

After running `w | awk '{if (NR!=1) {print $1,$5 }}'`, my output is like this

```
kha 10days
kha -
```

Comment: Have you seen https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/191436/linux-w-command-get-idle-time-in-seconds?

Comment: Yes, check my update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idle time measured by `w` is simply indicating how long since something was typed on the terminal a process is attached to.  As seen e.g. [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/283337/what-does-idle-time-output-from-w-command-tell) this is inaccurate for actually measuring user activity, since they might be using solely graphical input and not typing anything.

If your users are logged into an X11 session, the X client library has its own idle timer which can be queried; see e.g. [User idle time being reset to 0 after 30 secs on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4721389/user-idle-time-being-reset-to-0-after-30-secs-on-linux)

Cloud monitoring systems appear to examine things like CPU load and network traffic to decide when to declare an instance as idle. They probably have a baseline of system processes which can be ignored, and then simply add a tick whenever a non-system process is detected.

For your use case, perhaps a simple network monitoring tool would be the easiest to set up. If your users are always logged in over SSH, check for traffic on port 22; if there is none over several minutes, the instance is idle.  For X11 sessions, something similar could be set up for X protocol traffic (ports typically in the range from 6000 up).